# SQL database ID incrementation

Tags: sql-server, winforms

```
[ID]                   INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
```

Hi i am new to sql database and would like to know how do I create a integer ID where the ID starts from 001 and increments to 002 once a new data is created. I am only able to create a ID using the identity (1,1) function which only increment on a single digit. Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: You can't expect an `Int` column to have leading zeros, that would require a string (`varchar`) column type. So - short answer is no, unless you implement it via code, which is highly unrecommended.

Comment: `001` isn't an int - have you considered simply padding your int identity when displaying it?

Comment: May i know how to I go about creating data where the ID auto generates to display the following example (IT001, IT002) when there is 100 data, it reaches to IT100).

Comment: Filburt is correct.  You are confusing the IDENTITY data with your need to display it a certain way.  Those are two separate concerns...don't try to make them one.

Comment: and if it reaches 1000 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave your identity as it is and simply

```
SELECT CONCAT('IT', LPAD(ID, 3, '0')) AS ID
```

An `IDENTITY` column isn't meant to be loaded with additional information - it should only serve as a unique identifier for its record.

Comment: and if ID reaches 1000 ?

Comment: That's up to the OP - he only stated it will reach `IT100`.

Comment: Yes I agree but it seemed something to note anyway. He might not have considered that his ID column can grow larger then 999

Comment: As it stands, it's not even clear if the OP actually uses MySql - it looks more like MS SQL to me. Huge learning curve ahead.

Comment: Yes i am using MS SQL. I need the ID to reach above IT1000 too. Sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: @EGS If you are using MS SQL and need to cater for identity up to INT max value I'll have to change my answer.